# Issue with onBlur event nicEditor JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I'm trying to copy the content from a [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com) instance when the content changes:

```
var myInstance  = new nicEditor({  iconsPath : 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
    var nicInstance = nicEditors.findEditor('drag_words_paragraph');
    var drag_words_paragraph11 = nicInstance.getContent();
    $("#list_id").html(drag_words_paragraph11);
});
```

Instead, when I click anywhere on the page, I get an alert. How can I fix this?

Comment: Edited lightly for increased legibility.

Comment: What alert are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry.Its not alert.$("#list_id").html(drag_words_paragraph11); this will add content to div wherever I click on webpage

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previous answer try the following snippet.Let me know if you get any error. here the alert is fired only when the text is changed.

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEdit.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" name="drag_words_paragraph" id="drag_words_paragraph">
  Enter your text here...
</textarea>
<br/>
<p id="list_id"></p>
<script>
  var drag_words_paragraph;

  $(function() {
    window.drag_words_paragraph = $('#drag_words_paragraph').text();

    var myInstance = new nicEditor({
      iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
    }).panelInstance('drag_words_paragraph');
    myInstance.addEvent('blur', function() {
      debugger;
      var text = this.instanceById('drag_words_paragraph').getContent();
      if (window.drag_words_paragraph == text) {
        $("#list_id").html(text);
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('text changed');
        window.drag_words_paragraph = text;
        $("#list_id").html(text);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this code @karthikeyan Instead of blur function Can i use onchange because It changes some content outside also.Instaed of click outside onchange is much better

Comment: nicEditor only supports these events as mentioned in thier docs [http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/518/Editor%20Events)

Comment: Oh Okie @karthikeyan